# Chaotic order in DataTableOutput and strange computeFeature plot from multiframe image

Tags: r, image-processing, plot, shiny, dt

I'm programming a shiny app for image analysis using R and EBImage package.
After some difficulties, I have some good results, but at time to plot results of computeFeatures, I have some strange behaviour:

- I have to explicit order "cell" column to correctly present datatableoutput data.
- Plots have inverted order of "frame" factor.
- Distribution plot shows frames do not share common pixels dimensions of image. See that there is not overlapping of coordinate x and coordinate y between frames. It means like frames are not in the same position.

Here is an example:

```
library(EBImage)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

ui <- basicPage(
  column(
    width = 3,
    h3("Images"),
    displayOutput("nuc"),
    displayOutput("nucbw")
    ),
  column(
    width = 9,
    h3("Cell Features"),
    DT::dataTableOutput("basicfeatures"),
    hr(),
    fluidRow(
      column(
        width = 4,
        plotOutput("plot1")
        ),
      column(
        width = 8,
        plotOutput("plot2")
        )
      )
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output) {

  # Load Image
  nuc <- readImage(system.file("images", "nuclei.tif", package="EBImage"))
  # Segmented Image
  nucbw <- bwlabel(nuc > 0.5)

  # Display Original Image
  output$nuc <- renderDisplay(display(nuc))

  # Display Segmented Image
  output$nucbw <- renderDisplay(display(nucbw))

  # Compute Features
  features <- reactive({
    # Create empty dataframe
    data <- data.frame()
    # Obect to save total cell number
    ntotal <- 0L
    # Compute for each frame
    for (i in 1:numberOfFrames(nuc)){
      nobjects <- max(nucbw[,,i])
      cell <- seq.int(from = ntotal + 1L, length.out = nobjects)
      ntotal <- ntotal + nobjects
      # Create frame column to know the frame where each cell belongs
        frame <- rep(paste("Frame", i, sep = " "), nobjects)
      # Create features dataframe
        x1 <- computeFeatures.basic(nucbw[,,i], nuc[,,i])
        x2 <- computeFeatures.shape(nucbw[,,i], nuc[,,i])
        x3 <- computeFeatures.moment(nucbw[,,i], nuc[,,i])
      # Binding dataframe for each frame
        bind <- cbind(cell, frame, x1, x2, x3)
      # Binding dataframe different frame
        data <- rbind(bind, data)
    }

# Convert "cell" to numeric
    cell <- as.numeric(as.character(data$cell))
# "frame" remains untouched
    frame <- data$frame
# Convert computeFeatures to numeric
    temp <- as.data.frame(data.matrix(data[,-c(1,2)]))
# Binding to a unique data frame
    data <- cbind(cell, frame, temp)

    data
  })


  # Render Features Table
  output$basicfeatures <- DT::renderDataTable(
    features(),
    rownames = FALSE,
    caption = "Cell Features",
    extensions = list(
      "ColReorder" = NULL,
      "FixedHeader" = NULL
    ),
    options = list(
      pageLength = 10,
      colReorder = TRUE,
      fixedHeader = TRUE,
      scrollX = TRUE,
      order = list(0, 'asc')
    )
    )

  data2 <- reactive({
    features() %>%
      group_by(frame) %>%
      summarise(n = n())
  })

  output$plot1<- renderPlot({
    g <- ggplot(data2(), aes(x = frame, y = n)) +
      geom_col(aes(fill = frame), color = "black") +
      labs(title = "NUMBER OF CELLS PER FRAME", x = "FRAME", y = "NUMBER OF CELLS") +
      theme_bw(base_size = 16) +
      theme(legend.position = "none") +
      theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 14))
    g
  })

  output$plot2<- renderPlot({
    g <- ggplot(features(), aes(x = m.cx, y = m.cy, fill = frame, color = frame)) +
      geom_point(shape = 21, size = 4, alpha = 0.2) +
      labs(title = "DISTRIBUTION OF CELLS", x = "COORDINATE X", y = "COORDINATE Y") +
      theme_bw(base_size = 16) +
      theme(
        rect = element_rect(colour = "red"),
        strip.background = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = "white"),
        strip.text.x = element_text(colour = "black"),
        strip.text.y = element_text(colour = "black")
        ) +
      facet_wrap(~ frame, nrow = 1)
    g
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Doing `data <- rbind(data,bind)` instead of `data <- rbind(bind, data)` should solve your problem relating to order.

Comment: You are right. It solves the first two points of my issues. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that your intermediate character data representation is stored using factors, and the call to `data.matrix` replaces factors by their internal codes rather than the numbers they stand for. The simplest way around this is to set `options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` after the `library` calls.

However, you should avoid converting to characters in first place. This coercion happens when the numeric feature matrices `x1`, `x2`, `x3` are `cbind` with the `frame` character vector. This happens because `character` is the common denominator of these different data types. But you can avoid this by already creating a `data.frame` here: `bind <- data.frame(cell, frame, x1, x2, x3)`. Then all the data conversion steps after the `for` loop are not necessary anymore.

Comment: Perfect, it's working fine, but only a detail: when plotting the "distribution plot" I still need to convert "m.cx" and "m.cy" to numeric variable to correctly plot as a continuous variable. Thanks for your help. I see that you are developing EBImage and RBioFormats packages, that's awesome work, congrats. I'm using them a lot.

Comment: Right, you still need to do this if you decide to go for `options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`. However, as I pointed out, this is an inferior solution to the latter one which doesn't include the coercion to `character`. You should avoid any unnecessary data conversions, especially in a Shiny app's code because these affect the responsiveness of the app. If my answer solved your issue you might consider accepting and/or up-voting it.

Comment: Thanks for recommendations. I was not including correctly the "bind <- data.frame(cell, frame, x1, x2, x3)" data.frame into the loop. It must be positioned after the "bind <- cbind(cell, frame, x1, x2, x3)". Thanks a lot